# How to detect android apps that can handle requested Intent action?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to share text message trough twitter, facebook or in other ways that available on device. I wrote next code:

```
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here's some text for Twitter.");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share this via"));
```

But if no apps that can hadle this action, the "no such apps" dialog appears on screen. I want to detect these apps and disable this function if there is no handlers found. How I can do it?

Comment: BTW, be sure to call `setType()` on your `Intent` to indicate the MIME type of the text you are placing in `EXTRA_TEXT`.

Comment: Yes, adding `share.setType("text/plain");` works

Answer (score 24):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent...
    PackageManager manager = mContext.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
        //You have at least one activity to handle the intent
    } else {
        //No activity to handle the intent.
    }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try this. Next question - I was install twitter client, but my code don't activaye it. Is there are errors in my code?

Comment: As CommonsWare said, try setting the mime type of your content.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(pm) == null) {
    // activity not found
}
```

Comment: The answer is not complete, and besides there's a much older complete answer saying basically the same