# Android WebViewClient redirects to facebook, back button becomes messed up

Tags: android

So I have an internal browser in my app. When given a facebook address, Android takes over and opens Facebook app instead... This gives an interesting effect with back button on phone since the backbutton takes the user back to the viewview... which then again opens the facebook app... This gives an interesting effect with the...

Is there any way to "catch" such a situation and remove the "history" for the WebViewClient?

Answer (score 0):

You can override shouldOverrideUrlLoading(), like so:

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
                // detect facebook url, respond accordingly
    }
}
```

Checking if facebook (or some other handler) is installed is explained here:
[How to detect android apps that can handle requested Intent action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961280/how-to-detect-android-apps-that-can-handle-requested-intent-action)

And you can make sure that if you returned to your app, not to reload the same redirection page.